# Whats the issue with this stored procedure code ?

Tags: mysql

The code below is giving many semicolons related errors. I am new to `MySql`, so clue-less.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_get_orderbystatus`(p_status_id int)

BEGIN
declare v int;
if(p_status_id = 1) then
begin
    set v = 1;
end;
end if;

END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to change the `DELIMITER` if you're trying to execute this in `mysql` cli.

```sql
DELIMITER // -- change the delimiter to '//' 

CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_get_orderbystatus`(p_status_id int)
    DECLARE v INT;
    -- the rest of the code of your procedure
END//

DELIMITER ; -- change it back to ';'
```

> [**Defining Stored Programs**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-programs-defining.html)
>   If you use the mysql client program to define a stored program containing semicolon characters, a problem arises. By default, mysql itself recognizes the semicolon as a statement delimiter, so you **must redefine the delimiter temporarily** to cause mysql to pass the entire stored program definition to the server.

Answer (score 1):

try:
delimiter //
YOUR PROCEDURE HERE
END//

delimiter ;

Comment: peterm explained the same but better :)